# local webpage is still loading for using while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

When I am using for loop it's working perfectly but when I try to run this code with while loop and it's stuck loading.

```js
// for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
//    document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", 
//        function () {
//            alert("Hi there! I'm working ");
//        }
//    );
// }

var i = 0;
while (i < 7) {
    document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", 
        function () {
            alert("Hi there! I'm working ");
            i++;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: the while loop is infinite here because `i++` is inside the event listener which never runs

Comment: That means a lot to me!

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent loop with while

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 7) {
    document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert("Hi there! I'm working ");
  });
  i++;
}
```

What your previous code did, is that it kept on adding an event listener that would try to update the `i` variable on click but since your page never loaded, it did not have the chance (nor would the code be correct if it did).

Comment: Minor correction: `i++` should appear at the end of the loop instead of the start.

Comment: Agreed! To make it exactly the same as the for loop and maintain behavior, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution can be as easy as this:

```js
// for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
//    document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", 
//        function () {
//            alert("Hi there! I'm working ");
//        }
//    );
// }

var i = 0;
while (i < 7)
    document.querySelectorAll("button")[i++].addEventListener("click", 
        function () {
            alert("Hi there! I'm working ");
        }
    );
```

```html
<button>a</button><br>
<button>b</button><br>
<button>c</button><br>
<button>d</button><br>
<button>e</button><br>
<button>f</button><br>
<button>g</button><br>
<button>h</button>
```